# The origin of lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: regex

The question is about lookahead and lookbehind assertion.

Reference to lookahead:

> ```
> (?=...)
> ```
>
> Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string.
>   This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?=Asimov)
>   will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'.

Match Issac and look its behind, but called "lookahead".

While:

> ```
> (?<=...)
> ```
>
> Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match
>   for ... that ends at the current position. This is called a positive
>   lookbehind assertion. (?<=abc)def will find a match in 'abcdef', since
>   the lookbehind will back up 3 characters and check if the contained
>   pattern matches.

Match `def` and check its head for `abc` but called "lookbehind".

I am very confused about the unintuitive name of lookbehind and lookahead. Where do the names originate?

Comment: It's pretty clear for me, it matches `Issac ` and the lookahead make sure there is `Assimov` ahead, it's well named `lookahead`. I don't understand your question.

Comment: Funny question. To me it's very intuitive that the *lookahead* assertion looks ahead for `Asimov` and the *lookbehind* looks behind for `abc` :)

Comment: I think it's more of a "forward" / "backward" interpretation rather than "after" / "before".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: After reading @revos comment I'm better understanding your question. Seems like for your understanding e.g. in `abc` the `c` is *behind* the `b` and the `a` *ahead* of the `b`? Just imagine as the parser proceeds in the string, characters to the left, that are passed are *behind* and character to the right are *ahead*.

Comment: Since the target is "issac",  so we lookarond Issarc. focus on the target, focus on the pattern. I'm looking for the target, so I first place my eyes on the target.  the names of lookahead or lookhehind is  anti-intuitive but it silly easy to understand just remember anti-intuitive, my question where does it origniate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

While [Rex](https://pixabay.com/de/vectors/dinosaurier-tyrannosaurus-rex-dino-309918/) walks from start to end of the string, some things are ahead and others behind.

Comment: amazing explanation and I got the idea of 'forward' and 'backward'.

Comment: That's brilliant