# Regex where substring isn't found in pattern in specific location

Tags: regex, regex-negation, swiftlint

I am trying to build a (multiline) pattern for a linter, to catch cases where:

1. There is a `Text(` declaration
2. That is **not** followed by `.appFont(` declaration...
3. ...before the next occurrence of `}` (end of function) or `Text(` (another Text declaration...)

After many hours on regex101 (and consulting gpt...) I got these 2:

```
Text\([\s\S]*?\)[\s\S]*?(?!\.appFont)
```

This just catches the part that's before the `.appFont`, but I want the entire catch to fail if `.appFont` is found...

```
Text\([\s\S]*?\)[\s]*?(?!appFont)[\s\S]\}
```

This just catches everything, ignoring `appFont` being in the sting entirely...

In the following example, only the 2nd case should be captured:

```
Text("blah") 
  .appFont(.body)
}

Text("blah") 
}

Text(
  "blah"
)
.appFont(.blah)
}
```

I tried to read about negative lookahead but I think I still somehow just use it wrong, or somehow cause it to be ignored when I add `[\s\S]` maybe?

Comment: A lot depends on the tool. A lot of tools evaluate regexes one line at a time, so there's no way to write a regex that can check the next line. (Consider that a regex would end up having to check the _entire_ file and handle deeply nested functions, etc)

Comment: Have you tried working with [negation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)? Something [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/99hlyp/1). Depends on exact requirements.

Comment: Further worth to try with [this variant](https://regex101.com/r/xenhiQ/1) if the `.appFont` can occur later on but before the next `}`.

Comment: I didn't know about negation being a thing! Your last variant looks like it should do it but it mistakingly captures if `Text` and `appFont` are in the same line like so: `Text("blah").appFont(.foo)`, can't tell why that happens from the regex you wrote?

Comment: @AvielGross Was my slip to put the lookahead behind `[^}]` it should be *before* [like this update](https://regex101.com/r/xenhiQ/2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) together with a *negative* [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
Text\([^)]*\)(?:(?!\.appFont)[^}])*}
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wqPlY2/1) - A bit similar to [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

| regex | explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `Text` | match the substring |
| `\([^)]*\)` | match `(` followed by [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [non-`)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) *negated class* up to next closing `)` |
| `(?:(?!\.appFont)[^}])*}` | `(?:` [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions)`)` repeated `*` [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of times, containing: `(?!\.appFont)` a *neg.* [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that checks in front of each [non-`}`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) if substring `\.appFont` is not ahead - *consumes* on success each matching character up to `}` |

---

Or alternatively use the lookahead assertion just once after closing `)`.

```
Text\([^)]*\)(?![^}]*?\.appFont)[^}]*}
```

[Another demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wo6jQS/1) - Might even be a bit more efficient here.

| regex | explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `Text` | match the substring |
| `\([^)]*\)` | match `(` followed by [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [non-`)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) up to the next closing `)` |
| `(?![^}]*?\.appFont)` | neg. lookahead (*condition*): [look](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) if `[^}]*?\.appFont` is not ahead where `[^}]*?` matches [lazily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [non-`}`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) up to the substring `\.appFont` |
| `[^}]*}` | if the condition succeded (it's not ahead) consume [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [non-`}`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) up to `}` |

Comment: Amazing! thank you! So why does the 2nd option has the nageted character `[^}]` twice?

Comment: @AvielGross Welcome! A lookahead is an assertion triggered [at certain positions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59115730/5527985). In the second solution the lookahead-check `(?![^}]*?\.appFont)` is done after the closing parentheses `)`. If the condition succeeds, the matching `[^}]*}` proceeds. In the first solution the lookahead is contained in a repitition and fired at each position (can be costly/depening on input).

Comment: ok that makes sense now thank you so much for the help and extra details!! I would vote twice if I could :)